# How to access psd note text with jsx?

Tags: photoshop, jsx

I am trying to write a Photoshop script (jsx) that processes psd images. To make it possible to place individual processing values and options for my script into any psd I think about reading text that was stored in a Note.

Question: How can I read text that was placed in a psd file using the Note tool from within a jsx script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use one of the fileInfo fields if I want to stash some script related info in my document.  These are easily accessible from your jsx via activeDocument.documentInfo.